# How to populate 3D chart in Winforms Chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I would like to create 3D plots using Winforms in C#. All I can find on the Microsoft site is how to turn on 3D mode. There are no examples of how to actually populate data with X,Y and Z values. Examples use DataPoints, which only have X and Y. Can somebody point me to an example with a series of X Y and Z values?

Answer (score 2):

Winform charts don't support 'real' 3D plots. The 3D surface plots it supports are just the extending of multiple data series in the depth dimension.

Or another interpretation: the y-values of all data series are the function values of functions on the x-[data series index] plane.

So just create some data series with x-y-values and the data series index will be your z-value.

Comment: Not sure I understand this. Are you saying I need to create a separate X-Y series for each distinct Z-value? If so, how do I specify what the value is?

Answer (score 0):

In .Net6+ you can try to use [this port](https://github.com/kirsan31/winforms-datavisualization) of `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization`.
It has a `ZDepthRealCalc` 3DStyle mode which allows you to set the Z coordinate for the series. [More info](https://github.com/kirsan31/winforms-datavisualization/blob/dev/Docs/ZDepthRealCalc/ZDepthRealCalc.md).